# What can we do in MySQL 5.0 replication to address bandwidth concerns?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am developing an application to run on the client PC (Win) which is configured with a MySQL server 5.1 instance that will act as read-only slave to the remote master.  The remote master has dozens of schemas, but I only need one per client so I supply the **replication-do-db** setting in my.ini to only replicate the schema that the client needs.  The replication works, but when our clients get into regions of the world where internet access is only available via 3G wireless, which charge by data usage, they quickly exceed their data plan limits and run into expensive problems.

As I understand it, MySQL writes all transactions for all schemas into a single binlog file which means that each client has to download all of the transactions that are performed on every schema on the master, then once downloaded, apply the database filter per **replication-do-db** settings in the client's my.ini file.

To minimize this inefficiency I have employed the **slave_compressed_protocol = 1** setting, which seems to reduce the transmitted data by 50%, but still causes our client's to quickly exceed their data limit rack up the 3G bill.

I can't imagine I'm the only one facing this, so I'm sure I'll get a ton of answers on how to achieve this by setting x = y.  However, I can't find any documentation of such a setting, nor a recommended approach to take.

So far, here's my thought to a possible solution, please provide feedback or alternate routes:

---

1. Set up a "proxy" slave for each schema (on different box, or same box with a different MySQL instance/port)
2. Configure the proxy slave to replicate-do-db only the one database that the clients wish to replicate.
3. Configure the client's MySQL instance as slaves to the appropriate proxy slave.

This **should** result in the client only pulling the binlog data for their schema.  The downside (as far as I can tell) is that it dramatically increases the complexity of our setup, likely making it more fragile.

Thoughts?  Will this approach even work?

Note, we are running the MySQL 5.0 server on RedHat, but we could upgrade to 5.5 if it produces a solution.

Comment: I recommend asking this question at http://dba.stackexchange.com the real database experts are there.

Comment: @Lyke, so would you recommend another DBMS? MSSQL? The replication to moving clients works well, its just too fat.

Comment: I suggest reading `High performance MySQL second edition` http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718 It has a very interesting chapter *(chapter 8 IRC)* on replication.

Comment: Thanks again @Johan. I'll pick up a copy.  FYI, I've re-posted this at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns per your suggestion.

Comment: I addressed this question already in the DBA Stack Exchange : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns/3107#3107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addressed this question already in the DBA Stack Exchange : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns/3107#3107

I do not want to double dip in the Stack Exchange. Moderators, please close this !!!

Comment: a much better answer then mine as well +1

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

1.) Try using the --replicate-do-table option and specify only the tables you want

2.) Try using the --replicate-wild-do-table=name ..you should be able to filter all your tables this way if your tables have a unique name

[MySQL docs on table replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table)

Comment: This was answered like @RolandoMySQLDBA pointed out in the dba exchange and this should be closed.  However, for those that might find this instead of the db exchange - the settings you suggest still cause every transaction to be transferred to the slave as the filtering doesn't happen until the slave has the binlog updates from the master.